# SQL Aggregate output

Tags: sql, group-by

Consider below table as output of a complex nested query on multiple tables with around 1,00,000 records and I will use this query as sub query and name it as `People` in my main  query

```
    NAME    Age
    Dave    30
    Susan   32
    Susan   27
    Amy     22
    Amy     23
    Amy     20
```

I want the out put for above table as

```
    NAME    Count1   Age
    Dave    1        30
    Susan   2        32
    Susan   2        27
    Amy     3        22
    Amy     3        23
    Amy     3        20
```

With my query `SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS Count1 FROM People group by Name`
I get the output as:

```
    NAME    Count1
    Dave    3
    Susan   3
    Amy     3
```

So above query has to be modified... `People` is a huge sub query and I don't want to use it multiple times in my main SQL query...

I am new to SQL, any help from you would be very helpful...

Comment: Where is the *above* table?

Comment: hi @hims056, I have updated, you can consider this as Query on MS Access

Comment: @user1992408 is the second table your expected output? :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SELECT name,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM mytable t WHERE t.name = name) AS count1,
   age
FROM mytable
```

Comment: thanks mvp, but here `mytable` is a compled SQL, in my case is to compare two huge tables.

Comment: Save this complicated query as `people` view using `CREATE VIEW` and use it then just the way I proposed. I don't think you will find better solution. Note that performance may suck unless you have index for `name` column in the table where it originally came from (not even talking about other indexes necessary to make that view work fast).

Comment: No I am not running this against any data base, I am using ADODB using  VB Scripting on Huge Text Files using MS Text Driver... (here folder is data base and files are tables). So any read queries on MS access should work here too, but cant create views... I am not sure If I can create intermediate table (that represent new .txt file in folder) checking for the same....

Comment: Mean while can you suggest using `mytable` only once in query is feasible?

Comment: Some thing like `select t.name, m.Count1, t.age from (SELECT count(name) as count1 FROM mytable t WHERE t.name = m.name) AS m`

Comment: No, you have to refer to table twice to do implicit or explicit self-join.

Comment: Text Driver and 1,000,000 rows? You've got to be kidding. Convert your text into real SQL first and only then come here once again.

Comment: I am not kidding, and its working fine, this is used for re-conciliation of payments between two diff out put files from mainframe... that comes in text format with field separator... and MS text Driver supports 255 or 256 columns and no limitations on rows...

Comment: I cant copy it in excel 2003 that I have as its is more then 65K records... for all your practical consideration you can assume that I am using MS Access, and any select query there works here too...

Comment: You will have you import your text files into anything that even looks like real SQL - it could be Access (god forbid), SQLite, or serious SQL engine like Postgres, MySQL, MSSQL, whatever. **Anything** I mentioned will be able to execute statement I gave you or **any** other solution you will find, because **there will be join somewhere**.

Comment: Hi mvp, migrating to data base increases execution time, I found a way to create an intermediate way and hence not to execute the query that takes around 30 seconds twice....

Comment: I simply created an Intermediate table using the query similar to `Sql = "SELECT * INTO New.txt FROM Test.txt"'

Comment: Sql = "`SELECT * INTO New.txt FROM Test.txt`"

Comment: Thanks for giving a clue on creating new views.. That helped.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can join the same table like this:

```
SELECT P.name, counts, age FROM People P
JOIN (SELECT Name, COUNT(NAME) AS COUNTS FROM People GROUP BY NAME) P1
ON P.Name = P1.Name;
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2f47/14)

Comment: This demonstrates **explicit** join. My solution is **implicit** one. Just another way to slice an apple - result and performance should be the same.

Comment: hi @mvp, @hims056 both helped me to to come up with the final answer... here `People` is a sub query taking around 30 seconds to execute and I don't want to use it twice. So I created Intermediate Table using `Select Into` statement... As views were not supported...

Comment: @user1992408: Then you should accept answer that was most helpful for you. And you should upvote answers that you liked (accepting will also increase your own reputation). As new user, you cannot upvote yet, but you can get back and upvote once you gain 15 reputation.